# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.DateTime>' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, linq

**My modal**

```
Public class Details{
    public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
Details.Startdate = db.Bill.Where(u => u.BillId == Maxbillid).Select(u => u.EndDate );
Details.EndDate = db.Bill.Where(u => u.BillId == Maxbillid).Select(u => u.EndDate );
```

**Error**

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.DateTime'"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault`

> `FirstOrDefault` can return null, this code doesn't check for that

```
Details.Startdate = db.Bill.FirstOrDefault(u => u.BillId == Maxbillid).Startdate;
Details.EndDate = db.Bill.FirstOrDefault(u => u.BillId == Maxbillid).EndDate;
```

A more elegant design would be

```
var bill = db.Bill.FirstOrDefault(u => u.BillId == Maxbillid);

if (bill != null)
{
    Details.Startdate = bill.StarDate;
    Details.EndDate = bill.EndDate;
}
```

Or you could `Project` straight into `Details` with `Linq`

```
var details = db.Bill.Where(u => u.BillId == Maxbillid)
                    .Select(bill => new Details
                       {
                           Startdate = bill.StarDate,
                           EndDate = bill.EndDate
                       })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

More Resources from Msdn

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method (IEnumerable)](http://Enumerable.FirstOrDefault%3CTSource%3E%20Method%20(IEnumerable%3CTSource%3E))

Answer (score 2):

You could use`FirstOrDefault` and you should check possible null value. Also, be careful about that hitting to database twice is obviously unnecessary;

```
//Just get the entity for one time
var bill = db.Bill.FirstOrDefault(u => u.BillId == Maxbillid);   
if (bill != null)
{
    Details.Startdate = bill.StarDate;
    Details.EndDate = bill.EndDate;
}
```